# What happens to a socket that isn't explicitly closed? What if I make and connect to a new socket of the same parameters?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, network-programming

I am working with a piece of legacy C# code at the moment that does the following (modified for brevity):

```
var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddr, PortNumber);
clientSocket.Connect(ipEndPoint);
clientSocket.Receive(parameters);
clientSocket.Send(parameters);
```

ipAddress and Portnumber are generally the same (they'll rarely change, but they can and do occassionally).  Notice that there is no Socket.Close, Socket.Disconnect, Socket.ShutDown, or using statement.

Also, the server code is pretty much the same except its looping through a if(socket.Poll()) {socket.accept();...} loop. It doesn't close or disconnect or shutdown either.

Hypothetically:
What happens if I call this routine one time (keeping in mind the socket is not closed)?

What happens if I call this routine ten times, a second or two between each call?

Should I be 'closing' the socket, if so, how?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Since you're not specifying a local port when you initiate the connection, the OS will choose one for you when you make the connection.  So each time you call this function, you get a new TCP connection to the remote server, each with a different local port.

Comment: Are the TCP connections remaining open and consuming resources? Or do they somehow get closed automatically? 

I don't see how the program isn't getting slow/crashing/throwing exceptions after running for long periods of time. Maybe it is and I just haven't run it long enough to reach that point.

Comment: The connection will stay open until you close it.  if you run `netstat -an`, you'll see a list of the open TCP connections.  Depending on how often you do this, your app could run out of file descriptors.